# Android development of app crashes when button pressed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm very new to android development with zero knowledge on app development. I would like to seek for guidance and help to troubleshoot on a youtube example of account registration and login with using sqlite. I've follow the example carefully but the program ends up crashing when the button was pressed. the example can be found in
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVIZFV0Ttds

I'm using android studio 3.1.3. on my build.gradle, i've changed my compileSdkVersion 28 to 25 and targetSdkVersion to 25 as well as to match with the example in youtube to reduce build error.

As below are the codes that I think might be the cause of error within the databasehelper.java of the app

```
package com.example.weh.testsql.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.weh.testsql.model.User;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID +" INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + 
COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD +
            " TEXT" + ")";
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email){
        String[] columns ={
                COLUMN_USER_ID,
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if(cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
        String[] columns ={
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
                COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " =?" + " AND " +     COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD +" =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if(cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error are shown below on my logcat when running this application

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: user_email
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.weh.testsql, PID: 5240
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:     user_email (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE     user_email =?
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnec    tion.java:889)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>    (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>    (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDrive    r.java:44)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java    :1316)
                      at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                  at com.example.weich.testsql.sql.DatabaseHelper.checkUser(DatabaseHelper.java:61)
                  at com.example.weich.testsql.activities.RegisterActivity.postDataToSQLite(RegisterActivity.java:111)
                  at com.example.weich.testsql.activities.RegisterActivity.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:87)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Hey, did you try to update the version of your database? in const `DATABASE_VERSION`

Comment: @ruitercomp hi sorry as i am very very new to this, how can i update the version of database or rather where do i change it?

Comment: If you changed your columns after having run your app once, you'll need to re-create the table with the new setup. Uninstall/reinstall your app.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by changed your columns?

Comment: I mean, if you added, removed, renamed, etc., columns in your `DatabaseHelper`. Also, you currently have a typo in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, so you have changed something since the run that produced that stack trace, otherwise you would've never gotten as far as the `Exception` it's showing now. Change `INTERGER` to `INTEGER`, then, do the uninstall/reinstall.